# getting dead.letter file on Linux?

Tags: linux, mailx

i am sending mail to list of users, i am sending mail using `mailx` utility

```
mailx -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $FILE
```

its working fine with valid emails, but problem is that i am getting `dead.letter` file when i tried to send to mail id like `adffadf` , it string not a valid email,

expected - i want this `dead.latter` must not be occur even user having anything for email ID.

like `abc@gmail.com, abc@def.cc, adffdfs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page for my `mailx` says a lot of things about set `nosave` and so on, but they don't seem to work. The only way to stop your `dead.letter` file growing I have found is to replace it by a link to the special file /dev/null.

```
rm ~/dead.letter

ln -s /dev/null ~/dead.letter
```